# Android, Gridview and Touch and drag events

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

I am trying to set up a GridView of images that responds to onTouch. 
For example, if I swipe my finger across the screen horizontally, vertically or diagonally then I want the buttons which were touched to be selected. 
I tried setting OnTouchListener's for the imageview, but this didn't work, only the first imageview in the drag event received the onTouch events.